# RScript Regex pattern match invalid

Tags: rscript

I am trying to do a pattern match using RScript and Regex and I cant quite figure out why I keep getting Pattern Invalid errors. (RScript is new to me, Python is my comfort zone).

The pattern I am using is

```
^(?=.{8}$)[[:alpha:]]{2,5}[[:digit:]]{3,6}$
```

inside this

```
pattern <- "^(?=.{8}$)[[:alpha:]]{2,5}[[:digit:]]{3,6}$"
isValidEntity <- function(x) {grepl(pattern , as.character(x), ignore.case=TRUE)}
output <- within(dataset,{Valid=isValidEntity(dataset$entity)})
```

The error is:

```
invalid regular expression '^(?=.{8}$)[[:alpha:]]{2,5}[[:digit:]]{3,6}$', reason 'Invalid regexp'
```

Can anyone explain where I may be going wrong?

The pattern works perfectly if I write it out in a Python script and does what I need. (Changing the POSIX char classes for A-z and 0-9).

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Solved this.

Turning on "perl" option helped.

```
pattern <- "^(?=.{8}$)[[:alpha:]]{2,5}[[:digit:]]{3,6}$"
isValidEntity <- function(x) {grepl(pattern , as.character(x), ignore.case=TRUE, perl=TRUE)}
output <- within(dataset,{Valid=isValidEntity(dataset$entity)})
```